# C# TCP socket re-bind and listen after lost connection

Tags: c#

I have a simple TCP socket that sends images to a connected client. However, if the client disconnects, I get an exception (as I should):

```
Systems.Net.SocketException
```

How can I re-bind to the Socket in case of a lost connection, so after a disconnect the server starts listening again after a client disconnects?

Here is my source code and I hope someone can help me.

```
static void HandleServer()
        {
            int sent;
            Console.WriteLine("Server is starting...");
            byte[] data = new byte[1024];
            IPEndPoint ipep = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, 9050);

            Socket newsock = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork,
                            SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);

            newsock.Bind(ipep);
            newsock.Listen(10);
            Console.WriteLine("Waiting for a client...");

            Socket client = newsock.Accept();
            IPEndPoint newclient = (IPEndPoint)client.RemoteEndPoint;
            Console.WriteLine("Client {0} connected at port {1}!",
                            newclient.Address, newclient.Port);


            while(true)
            {
                 //send some data

            }
        }
```

Comment: Normally you enclose the `Accept()` call inside the loop, so you can have multiple connections.  Then, after each connection, you pass it off to another thread so it works independently of the other ones...

Comment: So do a while(true)  and accept inside and pass the client to the other loop. And how do i get back to the accept after a lost connection?

Comment: The outer loop would be still running, waiting for a connection.  So after they lose connection, they'll attempt to reconnect...and the loop will then give them a new connection...

Comment: Hi, thanks for your help. I extracted the binding into a own method and catched the exception. That fehlt more "correct" to me (personally). Thank you anyway for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Basically socket connection is matter of first listening then second detect.Any accepted connection come to your socket that you can separate this connection and listening continue.